# How to avoid target folder update in maven folder structure

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

We have created a framework to run our jmeter script using maven folder structure. This framework will create a reporting for every run when we run the test using "mvn verify" command. We need to customize the report to include some more details, but every time when we run maven command, it download the jmeter resource and update target folder in the framework. Due to this, all over customization we will cleared and not able to create expected report.
My POM look like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
   <artifactId>mvn-jmeter</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>maven-jmeter-demo</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                  <phase>verify</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>jmeter</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <generateReports>true</generateReports>
               <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                  <xms>1024</xms>
                  <xmx>1024</xmx>
                  <arguments>
                     <argument>-Xprof</argument>
                     <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
                  </arguments>
               </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
               <propertiesUser>
                  <testdatafile>${testdatafile}</testdatafile>
                  <suite>${suite}</suite>
               </propertiesUser>
               <testFilesIncluded>
                  <jMeterTestFile>testplans/${jmxfile}</jMeterTestFile>
               </testFilesIncluded>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Any help to resolve issue is much appreciated.

Comment: what mvn command do you launch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Basic Configuration chapter](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Basic-Configuration#basic-configuration)

> The following properties files will be used if they are found in **${project.base.directory}/src/test/jmeter**:
>
> - jmeter.properties
> - saveservice.properties
> - upgrade.properties
> - system.properties
> - user.properties
> - global.properties

So you can just perform required configuration overrides in *user.properties* file and put the file to the folder where your JMeter .jmx script(s) live. Maven plugin will pick this up and override the relevant values

---

Alternatively you can override any properties directly in your *pom.xml* file by specifying them under `configuration/propertiesJMeter` section.

Below example tells JMeter to store results as `xml` and save response data:

```
<propertiesJMeter>
    <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>xml</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
    <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>
</propertiesJMeter>
```

Full `pom.xml` just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-jmeter</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven-jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- save response data -->
                    <propertiesJMeter>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>xml</jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format>
                        <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>
                    </propertiesJMeter>
                    <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                    <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                        <xms>1024</xms>
                        <xmx>1024</xmx>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-Xprof</argument>
                            <argument>-Xfuture</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <testdatafile>${testdatafile}</testdatafile>
                        <suite>${suite}</suite>
                    </propertiesUser>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>testplans/${jmxfile}</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

More information:

- [Modifying Properties](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Result File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)